# Explain third party static lock behaviour used in synchronization in java

Tags: java, multithreading

```
    public class ObjectLevelLock implements Runnable{
        int count = 0;
        int uncount = 10;
        public static Object lock = new Object();
        public static Object lock1 = new Object();

        public void counter(){
            synchronized (lock) {
                for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"------"+count++);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                   // decrem();
                }
            }
        }

        public void decrem(){
            synchronized(lock1){
                for(int i =10; i>0; i-- ){
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"------"+uncount--);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void xxx(){
            while(true){
            decrem();
            counter();
            }   
        }

        public void run(){
                xxx();
                }

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            ObjectLevelLock obj1 = new ObjectLevelLock();
            ObjectLevelLock obj2 = new ObjectLevelLock();

            Thread t1 = new Thread(obj1,"Thread 1");
            Thread t2 = new Thread(obj2,"Thread 2");

            t1.start();
            t2.start();

        }

    }
```

On executing this program ,I get the following output at some point :

```
Thread 1------0
Thread 2------0
Thread 1-------1
Thread 2------1
Thread 1-------2
Thread 2------2
Thread 1-------3
Thread 2------3
Thread 1-------4
Thread 2------4
Thread 1-------5
Thread 2------5
Thread 2------6
Thread 1-------6
Thread 2------7
Thread 1-------7
Thread 1-------8
Thread 2------8
Thread 1-------9
```

---

As can be seen from output ,both threads are accessing the same method that's why both are incrementing count variable .Please let me know how is that possible ,if I am using static third party locks like

public **static** Object lock = new Object();

static means lock is acquired on the class which means is should be accessible by only one thread at a time.But then why then output trace showing both threads are in the same method and executing it concurrently.

Output should be :

One thread incrementing count variable other thread should be decrementing uncount variable and these two operation can also happen concurrently

Comment: I think it's doing what you think it should. Do you see that there's a different number of `-` on (almost) each successive line? Change your `println`: add `inc` and `dec`, and a space after all the `-`.

Comment: I'm not getting this output. When I run the program I get lots of `Thread 1` outputs before `Thread 2` kicks in.

Comment: I took the code, clarified the output by adding the method name. First thread 1 count down completely as Thread 2 is waiting for the lock. Then Thread 2 starts decrementing while Thread 1 increments. After a while Thread 1 and Thread 2 lines are alternation incrementing or decrementing in opposite direction.

Comment: I agree with @yasd's observations. OP, please check your assumptions and output corresponding to the program you posted.

Comment: Thanks guys ,I got it  I have not written print statements properly

Comment: _After a while Thread 1 and Thread 2 lines are alternation incrementing or decrementing in opposite direction._  Yes, they can do that because the two functions synchronize on different locks.  The two threads can never be in the same function at the same time, but one can be incrementing while the other is decrementing.  They tend to take turns writing lines to the console because of they way that System.out.println() works.